# Adding Cocoapods To Multiple Targets

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm needing to add Alamofire to my main iOS app and the iOS Today Extention. With Alamofire just being in my iOS app target, it works great! But now, I'm trying to add Alamofire to my today extention. This is my Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'The Main iOS App' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

pod 'Canvas'
pod 'Firebase/Core’
pod 'Firebase/Messaging’
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'

  # Pods for The Main iOS App

end

target 'Today' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'

  # Pods for Today

end
```

Whenever using `pod install` in terminal, I get this:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (4.5.0)
Using Canvas (0.1.2)
Using Firebase (4.0.3)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.2)
Using FirebaseCore (4.0.3)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.0)
Using FirebaseMessaging (2.0.0)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
Using Protobuf (3.3.0)
[!] The 'Pods-iFunnyVlogger' target has frameworks with conflicting names: alamofire.
```

How do I properly do this?

### UPDATE - Still Not Working

Some information that you may need is that I'm on cocoapods version 1.2.0 and I've tried `pod update`, but I'm still getting that error

> [!] The 'Pods-iFunnyVlogger' target has frameworks with conflicting
>   names: alamofire.

Comment: can you give me your cocoapod version number?
for know the version please run pod --version command.

Comment: @NilayShah My version is 1.2.0

Comment: Then please update a cocoapods with pod update. and then try is it working or not?

Comment: @NilayShah I've already tried that. It updates, and then I get the error `[!] The 'Pods-iFunnyVlogger' target has frameworks with conflicting names: alamofire.`

Comment: @NilayShah Any ideas? I've been looking into it.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

def other_pods
    pod 'Canvas'
    pod 'Firebase/Core’
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging’
end    

def shared_pods
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end

target 'The Main iOS App' do
    shared_pods
    other_pods
end

target 'Today' do
    shared_pods
end
```